# Sqlalchemy. Deep filtering by multiple parameters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have that DB:

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class Filter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'filter'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(ForeignKey("category.id"), nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    transcription = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    category = relationship('Category', backref='filters')


class FilterParameter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fparam'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    value = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    feature_id = Column(ForeignKey("filter.id"), nullable=False)
    transcription = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    filter = relationship('Filter', backref="fparams")


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    pic = Column(Text)
    price = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    availability = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    keywords = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class ProductParameter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pparam'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    product_id = Column(ForeignKey("product.id"), nullable=False)
    param_id = Column(ForeignKey("fparam.id"), nullable=False)

    product = relationship('Product', backref="pparams")
```

The goal is to filter the list of products by several parameters (and_). One product has a list of different parameters (one to many), these parameters are located in the FilterParameter table.

I think that I am already close to the goal, since the filter by one of the types of parameters works:

```
res = cursor.session.query(Product).join(ProductParameter, Product.id == ProductParameter.product_id)\
    .join(FilterParameter, FilterParameter.id == ProductParameter.param_id)\
    .join(Filter, Filter.id == FilterParameter.feature_id)

res = res.filter(FilterParameter.transcription.in_("acer,asus".split(',')),
                 Filter.transcription == "brand").all()
```

It works.

But if you need to filter by several types of parameters:

```
res = res.filter(and_(FilterParameter.transcription.in_("acer,asus".split(',')),
                 Filter.transcription == "brand"))\
    .filter(and_(FilterParameter.transcription.in_("1920x1080".split(',')), 
                 Filter.transcription == "pixel")).all()
```

It doesn`t work.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a more complicated problem then it seems.  I think you can use joins, subqueries or an array column (in postgresql if you are using that).

#### Just some setup code

Setup the models and populate the db

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    ForeignKey,
    Text,
)
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    and_,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_base,
    Session,
    relationship,
    aliased,
)


def get_engine(env):
    return create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}", echo=True)


Base = declarative_base()

class Filter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'filter'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    transcription = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class FilterParameter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fparam'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    feature_id = Column(ForeignKey("filter.id"), nullable=False)
    transcription = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    filter = relationship('Filter', backref="fparams")


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    tags = Column(ARRAY(Text))


class ProductParameter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pparam'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    product_id = Column(ForeignKey("product.id"), nullable=False)
    param_id = Column(ForeignKey("fparam.id"), nullable=False)

    product = relationship('Product', backref="pparams")



def populate(engine):
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    with Session(engine) as session:
        brand = Filter(transcription='brand')
        session.add(brand)
        brand_params = [FilterParameter(filter=brand, transcription=name) for name in ['acer', 'asus']]
        session.add_all(brand_params)
        pixel = Filter(transcription='pixel')
        session.add(pixel)
        pixel_params = [FilterParameter(filter=pixel, transcription=name) for name in ['1920x1080']]
        session.add_all(pixel_params)
        session.flush()
        p1 = Product(title="TV", tags=['brand--acer', 'pixel--1920x1080'])
        session.add(p1)
        session.add_all([ProductParameter(product=p1, param_id=brand_params[0].id), ProductParameter(product=p1, param_id=pixel_params[0].id)])
        session.commit()
```

#### Joining example

This option joins across ProductParameter, FilterParameter and Filter for every filter.  I think you could optimize this by prefetching the filters, like `"brand"`, to eliminate the join onto `Filter`.

```py
def filter_products_with_joins(session, filters):
    res = session.query(Product)
    for filter_name, filter_params in filters:
        pp = aliased(ProductParameter)
        fp = aliased(FilterParameter)
        f = aliased(Filter)
        res = res.join(pp, Product.id == pp.product_id)
        res = res.join(fp, and_(fp.id == pp.param_id, fp.transcription.in_(filter_params.split(','))))
        res = res.join(f, and_(f.id == fp.feature_id, f.transcription == filter_name))
    return res.all()
```

#### Subqueries example

This is similar to joining but might be faster and is more flexible/easier to read.  Instead of chaining the joins we just combine a subquery for each filter together with AND statements.  Ie. I want products whose ids are in the list of product ids with these brands AND in the list of product ids with these pixels, etc.

```py
def filter_products_with_subqueries(session, filters):
    subs = []
    for filter_name, filter_params in filters:
        res = session.query(Product.id)
        pp = ProductParameter
        fp = FilterParameter
        f = Filter
        res = res.join(pp, Product.id == pp.product_id)
        res = res.join(fp, and_(fp.id == pp.param_id, fp.transcription.in_(filter_params.split(','))))
        res = res.join(f, and_(f.id == fp.feature_id, f.transcription == filter_name))
        subs.append(res.subquery())
    return session.query(Product).filter(*[Product.id.in_(sub) for sub in subs]).all()
```

#### Using an array column example (postgres only I think)

This is a lot easier to query but harder to maintain.  In this case we squash the filter/filter params into tags (the combination of filter and filter param).  We setup our products with their tags and then query those tags with a list of tags.  Ie. I want products whose tags have these brand tags AND whose tags have these pixel tags, etc.

```py
def filter_products_with_tags(session, filters):
    tag_groups = []
    for filter_name, filter_params in filters:
        tag_groups.append([f'{filter_name}--{filter_param}' for filter_param in filter_params.split(',')])
    return session.query(Product).filter(*[Product.tags.overlap(tag_group) for tag_group in tag_groups]).all()
```

#### The rest of the code

Testing and main call.

```py
def query(engine):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        for func in (filter_products_with_joins, filter_products_with_subqueries, filter_products_with_tags):
            assert len(func(session, [('brand', 'acer,asus')])) == 1
            assert len(func(session, [('brand', 'acer,asus'), ('pixel', '1920x1080')])) == 1
            assert len(func(session, [('brand', 'acer,asus,sony'), ('pixel', '1920x1080')])) == 1
            assert len(func(session, [('brand', 'acer,asus,sony'), ('pixel', '480x360')])) == 0
            assert len(func(session, [('brand', 'acer,asus,sony'), ('pixel', '1920x1080,480x360')])) == 1




def main():
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)
    populate(engine)
    query(engine)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. 
This method works well. But I use SQLite and there is no ARRAY there, and I would also like to learn more about complex SQL queries. But I found a solution using Join and subQuery. Now I will post the answer with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way, and in my case it works well:

```
def dot_filters(query, args: dict):
""" Get filter args as dict, where key is Filter.transcription, and val is FilterParameter.transcription """

for key, val in args.items():  # Go to all filter args
    """ Create subquery where we back a list of Filter.id with Filter.transcription == key """
    sub_query = cursor.session.query(Filter.id).filter(Filter.transcription == key).scalar_subquery()
    """ Create subquery where we back a list of Product.id (from ProductParameter.product_id)
        with FilterParameter.transcription in val_list and necessary Filter.id subquery"""
    sub_query = cursor.session.query(ProductParameter.product_id).join(FilterParameter)\
        .filter(FilterParameter.feature_id.in_(sub_query),
                FilterParameter.transcription.in_(val.split(',')))\
        .scalar_subquery()
    """ Get list of Products from filtered list of ID`s """
    query = query.filter(Product.id.in_(sub_query))
return query
```

End used like:

```
query = dot_filters(query, args)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).